# Javascript: Namespace wrap up for normal function

Tags: javascript, oop

I have created functions as normal way, am just trying this in namespace way. the below that i have now, for the same i just want to know how this would be in Namespace way. Any idea?

Aim: I want this piece of code in Namespace wrap up with optimization of this code.

```
<div class="Content" id="ThiPage">
    <div class="something">
    <p></p>
    </div>

    <div class="text">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    </div>

</div>


<div class="Content" id="ThiPage1">
    <div class="something">
    <p></p>
    </div>

    <div class="text">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="Content" id="ThiPage2">
    <div class="something">
    <p></p>
    </div>

    <div class="text">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    </div>

</div>
```

My current JS code is

```
var sampPag = document.getElementById("ThiPage");
var sampPag1 = document.getElementById("ThiPage1");
var sampPag2 = document.getElementById("ThiPag2");


function samplefunct(thisArray){

sampPag.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = thisArray[1].heading;
sampPag1.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = thisArray[2].heading;
sampPag2.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = thisArray[0].heading;

//Body content
for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){

sampPag.getElementsByTagName("div")[1].getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML += thisArray[1].text;
sampPag.getElementsByTagName("div")[1].getElementsByTagName("p")[1].innerHTML += thisArray[1].text;
if (i == 1) {sampPag.getElementsByTagName("div")[3].getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src += thisArray[1].image;}

sampPag1.getElementsByTagName("div")[1].getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML += thisArray[2].text;
sampPag1.getElementsByTagName("div")[1].getElementsByTagName("p")[1].innerHTML += thisArray[2].text;
if (i == 1) {sampPag1.getElementsByTagName("div")[2].getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src += thisArray[2].image;}

sampPag2.getElementsByTagName("div")[1].getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML += thisArray[0].text;
sampPag2.getElementsByTagName("div")[1].getElementsByTagName("p")[1].innerHTML += thisArray[0].text;
if (i == 1) {sampPag2.getElementsByTagName("div")[2].getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src += thisArray[0].image;}

}
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate what is it exactly that you need? do you want to call the function in a namespace like way? mynamespace.myfunction ?

Comment: Yes, with optimized code for this, I have Jquery for that in my mind for that, Is that okay?

Comment: yes actually it's okay however your code can be optimized a little and for the name spacing @jdphenix gave an excellent example however exposing your namespace should be added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily move the fn into the new namespace. And add the js code in a separate external .js file.

```
var myns = {}; 
myns.globvar = {}; //global variables restricted to the namespace.
myns.funcs = {};   //Add your functions to the funcs. 

 myns.funcs.samplefunctest= function () {
             / * Code here */
}
```

Ref - http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#detailnamespacing

Answer (score 0):

This could be as simple as an IIFE:

```
(function () { 
  var sampPag = document.getElementById('ThiPage');
  var sampPag1 = document.getElementById('ThiPage1');
  var sampPag2 = document.getElementById('ThiPag2');
  function samplefunct(thisArray) {
    sampPag.getElementsByTagName('div') [0].getElementsByTagName('p') [0].innerHTML = thisArray[1].heading;
    sampPag1.getElementsByTagName('div') [0].getElementsByTagName('p') [0].innerHTML = thisArray[2].heading;
    sampPag2.getElementsByTagName('div') [0].getElementsByTagName('p') [0].innerHTML = thisArray[0].heading;
    //Body content
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      sampPag.getElementsByTagName('div') [1].getElementsByTagName('p') [0].innerHTML += thisArray[1].text;
      sampPag.getElementsByTagName('div') [1].getElementsByTagName('p') [1].innerHTML += thisArray[1].text;
      if (i == 1) {
        sampPag.getElementsByTagName('div') [3].getElementsByTagName('img') [0].src += thisArray[1].image;
      }
      sampPag1.getElementsByTagName('div') [1].getElementsByTagName('p') [0].innerHTML += thisArray[2].text;
      sampPag1.getElementsByTagName('div') [1].getElementsByTagName('p') [1].innerHTML += thisArray[2].text;
      if (i == 1) {
        sampPag1.getElementsByTagName('div') [2].getElementsByTagName('img') [0].src += thisArray[2].image;
      }
      sampPag2.getElementsByTagName('div') [1].getElementsByTagName('p') [0].innerHTML += thisArray[0].text;
      sampPag2.getElementsByTagName('div') [1].getElementsByTagName('p') [1].innerHTML += thisArray[0].text;
      if (i == 1) {
        sampPag2.getElementsByTagName('div') [2].getElementsByTagName('img') [0].src += thisArray[0].image;
      }
    }
  }
}());
```

This avoids creating any globals at all. One reference I use whenever considering module patterns is this page: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html. It has reasonable coverage of different JavaScript module patterns that exist.

Comment: Actually, I need this in namespace pattern in JS objects, Am just trying that just